# Swiftのif文での代入に関する質問です。

Tags: ios, swift

Swiftに関する質問です。
下記のコードが何故結果のようになるのかわかりません。

if let n = maybe のところはnという変数に変数maybeを代入しているんでしょうか？？
詳しい方、ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

```
var maybe : Int? = 1
if let n = maybe {
  n + 1
  // 2
}
```

Answer (score 9):

> if let n = maybe のところはnという変数に変数maybeを代入しているんでしょうか？？

`let`ですので、`n`は変数ではなく定数ですが、代入しているという理解で正しいです。

この構文は`Optional Binding`といって、代入結果が`nil`の場合then節を実行しないという特徴があります。

```
var maybe : Int? = nil
if let n = maybe {
  n + 1
  // do nothing
}
```